# Not being able to execute stl decomposition properly

Tags: r, stl, time-series, decomposition

from this ts:

```
australia_data <- tourism %>%
  select(Quarter, Trips) %>%
  summarise(TotalTrips = sum(Trips))

> head(australia_data)
# A tsibble: 6 x 4 [1D]
# Key:       Region, Purpose [1]
# Groups:    Region [1]
  Region   Purpose  Quarter    TotalTrips
  <chr>    <chr>    <date>          <dbl>
1 Adelaide Business 1998-01-01       135.
2 Adelaide Business 1998-04-01       110.
3 Adelaide Business 1998-07-01       166.
4 Adelaide Business 1998-10-01       127.
5 Adelaide Business 1999-01-01       137.
6 Adelaide Business 1999-04-01       200.
```

I want to do a STL decomposition, in order to get seasonally adjusted data :

```
australia_data_dcmp <- australia_data %>%
  model(STL(TotalTrips))
```

but I'm not being able to get components

```
> components(australia_data_dcmp)
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `cmp`.
i `cmp = map(.fit, components)`.
x no applicable method for 'components' applied to an object of class "null_mdl"


> head(augment(australia_data_dcmp))
# A tsibble: 6 x 8 [1D]
# Key:       Region, Purpose, .model [1]
  Region   Purpose  .model          Quarter    TotalTrips .fitted .resid .innov
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>           <date>          <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Adelaide Business STL(TotalTrips) 1998-01-01       135.      NA     NA     NA
2 Adelaide Business STL(TotalTrips) 1998-04-01       110.      NA     NA     NA
3 Adelaide Business STL(TotalTrips) 1998-07-01       166.      NA     NA     NA
4 Adelaide Business STL(TotalTrips) 1998-10-01       127.      NA     NA     NA
5 Adelaide Business STL(TotalTrips) 1999-01-01       137.      NA     NA     NA
6 Adelaide Business STL(TotalTrips) 1999-04-01       200.      NA     NA     NA
```

can someone explain me the mistake I'm commiting please ?

Best regards

Comment: Can't seem to reproduce your issue. It works fine on my side. Are you loading the fpp3 package or just fable and fabletools?

Comment: fpp3, is not the first time that similar situation happens

Comment: already uninstalled and reinstalled package and situation persists @phiver

Comment: same situation persists

Comment: restart and try: `library(fable) library(feasts) library(dplyr) data("tourism", package = "tsibble")` and then your code. If that doesn't work, start R without Rstudio and try this as well.

Comment: do you know if there's something i can do for it to work with fpp3 ?

Comment: There might be a conflict somewhere. The only thing you can do is to remove all the packages that are related to fpp3 and reinstall them. But there might be some other package that is causing the issue. There are quite a few that contain the function components. You might try and see what happens when you use `fabletools::components` in your code when you use fpp3.

Answer (score 0):

The `tourism` object you show is *not* what you get when using the latest versions of the various packages loaded by `fpp3`. This is what I get.

```r
library(fpp3)
#> ── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3 0.4.0 ──
#> ✓ tibble      3.1.5     ✓ tsibble     1.1.0
#> ✓ dplyr       1.0.7     ✓ tsibbledata 0.3.0
#> ✓ tidyr       1.1.4     ✓ feasts      0.2.2
#> ✓ lubridate   1.8.0     ✓ fable       0.3.1
#> ✓ ggplot2     3.3.5
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3_conflicts ──
#> x lubridate::date()    masks base::date()
#> x dplyr::filter()      masks stats::filter()
#> x tsibble::intersect() masks base::intersect()
#> x tsibble::interval()  masks lubridate::interval()
#> x dplyr::lag()         masks stats::lag()
#> x tsibble::setdiff()   masks base::setdiff()
#> x tsibble::union()     masks base::union()
australia_data <- tourism %>%
  select(Quarter, Trips) %>%
  summarise(TotalTrips = sum(Trips))
australia_data
#> # A tsibble: 80 x 2 [1Q]
#>    Quarter TotalTrips
#>      <qtr>      <dbl>
#>  1 1998 Q1     23182.
#>  2 1998 Q2     20323.
#>  3 1998 Q3     19827.
#>  4 1998 Q4     20830.
#>  5 1999 Q1     22087.
#>  6 1999 Q2     21458.
#>  7 1999 Q3     19914.
#>  8 1999 Q4     20028.
#>  9 2000 Q1     22339.
#> 10 2000 Q2     19941.
#> # … with 70 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Perhaps you are over-writing the `tourism` object with a grouped version. Or perhaps you are using an old version of the `tsibble` package where the keys were not dropped using `summarise()`.

In any case, without a reproducible example it is hard to provide more substantial help.